# SwiftUI - List memory allocation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Does the `List` in `SwiftUI` handle the cells like `UITableView` from `UIKit`, keeping in memory only the cells that are currently being displayed, reusing the already existing cell when the user scroll the list?

Comment: yes, it should be the same

Comment: Use the Memory Debugger and check it out for yourself! Lots of cool things to be seen/learned there

Answer (score 1):

`List` is just a wrapper around UITableView so it'll come with all the nice things.